# fetch the calculated text style without rendering the entire html in python

Tags: python, html

Given an HTML input

```
html='''This is <b>Bold</b> or <strong>Also Bold</strong> or even <font style="text-weight: bold">Style Bold</font>'''
```

I would like to filter out only the **bold** words

Note that this example is simplified, in my real use case I have millions of documents to process, with more structure and more html tags I do not care about.

```
result=["Bold","Also Bold","Style Bold"]
```

The main issue, is that there are several ways to set a font weight (HTML Tags / style sheets)

And I wonder if there is a python package that can render only the tags I care about and observe the result, or is the only way is to write a parser my self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is a dedicated library for selecting bold text. However, it's pretty easy with HTML parser like BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

input = """This is <b>Bold</b> or <strong>Also Bold</strong> or even <font style="text-weight: bold">Style Bold</font>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(input, "html.parser")

bold = soup.select("b, strong, [style*=bold]")

# > bold = [<b>Bold</b>, <strong>Also Bold</strong>, <font style="text-weight: bold">Style Bold</font>]

bold_textonly = list(map(lambda tag: tag.text, bold)) # extract text from tags

# > bold_textonly = ['Bold', 'Also Bold', 'Style Bold']
```

The `[style*=bold]` should match any tag with `font-weight: bold` or `bolder`. If you want just `<font>` tags, the selector would be `font[style*=bold]`.

[Working example at repl.it](https://repl.it/Gsow)

There are additional ways to create a bold text with some fonts, like `font-weight: 700` or so. But that would be easy to add, too.

And, of course, this only works for inline styles. Selecting text made bold by an external stylesheet would be more challenging…

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a universally reliably solution to cover all possible use cases (e.g. the font style may be set via CSS), but you can get closer to it and find all the `b` and `strong` elements as well as `font` elements with "bold" substring inside.

Working example using [`BeautifulSoup` library](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (using a [searching function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function)):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = '''This is <b>Bold</b> or <strong>Also Bold</strong> or even <font style="text-weight: bold">Style Bold</font>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")


def bold_only(tag):
    is_b = tag.name == 'b'
    is_strong = tag.name == 'strong'
    is_bold_font = tag.name == 'font' and 'style' in tag.attrs and 'bold' in tag['style']

    return is_b or is_strong or is_bold_font

print([bold.get_text() for bold in soup.find_all(bold_only)])
```

Prints:

```
['Bold', 'Also Bold', 'Style Bold']
```